# How to add values to the header from a filter in Spring Security?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am developing a web service with JWT in spring security and spring session. My intention is to add a filter that validates the JWT, extract its JTI and add it in the header service as "x-auth-token". The Json Web Token JTI matches the "Session_id" that generates spring session when a new user is authenticated (it can see with `RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().GetSessionId()`). This was put in the Json Web Token JTI when the user was authenticated.

I already have the filter that validates the JWT, however, I will not put it here now for simplicity. What I will put will be only the filter class with the written method doFilter.

What I'm trying to do is add a value to the header, something like this:

```
public class CustomFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(
      ServletRequest request, 
      ServletResponse response,
      FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        /*
         * In this part I validate the token and extract the JTI, which is equal to the session_id of spring session.
         * Suppose that JTI = 71b0b8c1-1eac-46ce-80b6-f14c2e08c0de
         */

        //I want to do something like this:
        request.addHeader("x-auth-token", "71b0b8c1-1eac-46ce-80b6-f14c2e08c0de");

        chain.doFilter(request, response);

    }
}
```

This way the spring session token will not be inserted by the user, but by the filter once it is extracted from the JWT.

I have tried to do it through a class that extends from HttpServletRequestWrapper, like this:

```
public class HeaderMapRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    /**
     * construct a wrapper for this request
     * 
     * @param request
     */
    public HeaderMapRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
    }

    private Map<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    /**
     * add a header with given name and value
     * 
     * @param name
     * @param value
     */
    public void addHeader(String name, String value) {
        headerMap.put(name, value);
    }

    @Override
    public String getHeader(String name) {
        String headerValue = super.getHeader(name);
        if (headerMap.containsKey(name)) {
            headerValue = headerMap.get(name);
        }
        return headerValue;
    }

    /**
     * get the Header names
     */
    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getHeaderNames() {
        List<String> names = Collections.list(super.getHeaderNames());
        for (String name : headerMap.keySet()) {
            names.add(name);
        }
        return Collections.enumeration(names);
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getHeaders(String name) {
        List<String> values = Collections.list(super.getHeaders(name));
        if (headerMap.containsKey(name)) {
            values.add(headerMap.get(name));
        }
        return Collections.enumeration(values);
    }

}
```

and defining the doFilter method like this:

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(
      ServletRequest request, 
      ServletResponse response,
      FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        /*
             * In this part I validate the token and extract the JTI, which is equal to the session_id of spring session.
             * Suppose that JTI = 71b0b8c1-1eac-46ce-80b6-f14c2e08c0de
             */

        HttpServletRequest r = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        HeaderMapRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new HeaderMapRequestWrapper(r);

        requestWrapper.addHeader("x-auth-token", "71b0b8c1-1eac-46ce-80b6-f14c2e08c0de");

        chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, response);

    }
```

However it does not work, I do not know if I have missed something or is not the way to do it.

**Edit 02/10/2017:**

When I run the service spring recognizes that there is no token (x-auth-token) in the header and automatically sends me the filter to authenticate the new user, which causes a Forbidden error because there is no user and password.

If I send the token (x-auth-token) from the beginning in the header everything works fine.

**Edit 05/10/2017:**

I have created an second filter to check the value that was added by the first filer in the header. The first filter does not receive the value "x-auth-token" from the ServletRequest, it adds it with "requestWrapper".

The second filter was added to configuration class like this:

```
 .addFilterAfter (getCustomFilter (),
 UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class) 
 .addFilterAfter
 (getCustomFilter2 (), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
```

where getCustomFilter () and getCustomFilter2 () were created using a bean like this:

```
@Bean
    public CustomFilter getCustomFilter(){
        return new CustomFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomFilter2 getCustomFilter2(){
        return new CustomFilter2();
    }
```

The second filter is defined as follows:

```
public class CustomFilter2  implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(
      ServletRequest request, 
      ServletResponse response,
      FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {     

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        System.out.println("Result: " + req.getHeader("x-auth-token"));
        chain.doFilter(request, response);

    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

When I run the service spring recognizes that there is no token (x-auth-token) in the original header and automatically sends me the filter to authenticate the new user.

I think the problem is the order in which spring session is executed.

How can I call spring session after our filters?

The configuration class is the follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity 
public class SeguridadConfiguracion extends  WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired 
    @Qualifier("seguridadServicio")
    private UserDetailsService objSeguridadServicio;

    @Autowired 
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception { 
        auth.userDetailsService(objSeguridadServicio); 
    } 

    @Override 
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
            http
              .authorizeRequests() 
                         .antMatchers("/**").hasAnyAuthority("ComisionadoSI","GerenciaSI")
                         .anyRequest().authenticated()
                         .and() 
             .logout().clearAuthentication(true)
                      .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                      .and()
             .formLogin()
                        .and()
             .httpBasic() 
                        .and()

             .addFilterAfter(getCustomFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
             .addFilterAfter(getCustomFilter2(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)

             .csrf().disable();

    }

    @Bean
    public CustomFilter getCustomFilter(){
        return new CustomFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomFilter2 getCustomFilter2(){
        return new CustomFilter2();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy() {
        return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
     }

}
```

Comment: _Edit 02/10/2012_?!

Answer (score 1):

We can do this via addingAttribute in the `filter`

httpServletRequest.setAttribute("key name","value");

And in `Controller` we can access them via `@RequestAttribute`

Comment: @balaagi: If i implement UserDetailsService in my custom class then in that class how can i access this attribute which was set in one of the class implementing  Filter?

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified the order of your filters to make sure this filter is executed in the correct order?

**Update to add more info:**

Looking at the spring docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#httpsession-rest

You enable spring session by adding the annotation `@EnableRedisHttpSession`.

> The @EnableRedisHttpSession annotation creates a Spring Bean with the
>   name of springSessionRepositoryFilter that implements Filter. The
>   filter is what is in charge of replacing the HttpSession
>   implementation to be backed by Spring Session. In this instance Spring
>   Session is backed by Redis.

According to this the springSessionRepositoryFilter is an instance of `springSessionRepositoryFilter`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/api/org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.html

> RedisHttpSessionConfiguration exposes the SessionRepositoryFilter as a bean named
>   "springSessionRepositoryFilter". In order to use this a single
>   RedisConnectionFactory must be exposed as a Bean.

Based on that, I think you need to add your filter before the `SessionRepositoryFilter` like:

```
.addFilterAfter(getCustomFilter(), SessionRepositoryFilter.class)
.addFilterAfter(getCustomFilter2(), SessionRepositoryFilter.class)
```

Comment: Hello mad_fox The service has two filters, the first one is to authenticate and generate the JWT and the second to validate later (it is named `CustomFilter`). however, by your comment, what I did was to disable the first filter once I got the JWT, in this way alone leave the validation filter (`CustomFilter`). The problem is that when the `x-auth-token` value is not in the header at startup, spring does not recognize it, even when I add it with `requestWrapper.addHeader ()`.

Comment: I added the filter with: `.addFilterAfter(new CustomFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)` in the configuration class that extends of  `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

Comment: Ey mad_fox, you were right, the mistake is because of the order. I tested with two custom filters. The first adds the x-auth-token value with HeaderMapRequestWrapper  and the second filter only reads the value from the request. It work very fine. But it continues sends me the filter to authenticate the new user. Like you said the order is no correct. Spring session is started in other moment. Do you know how can I do to call a filter before spring session starts?.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the file where your filters are added? Then I can provide some more info on how to set the ordering.

Comment: I'm asking if you can post the class that contains this code: .addFilterAfter (getCustomFilter (),
 UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class) 
 .addFilterAfter
 (getCustomFilter2 (), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class) That snippit isn't enough for me to provide a solution.

Comment: I see that you are are adding the filters after the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter. What happens is you use addFilterBefore instead?

Comment: I have updated the solution. I'm not 100% sure if that is correct, but basically, based on the documentation, you need to add your filters before the SessionRepositoryFilter